# ssh x forwarding and close terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin

I'm using 'ssh myremoteserver -f -X myprogram  1>/dev/null 2>&1' to launch a remote gui app. But when I close the terminal, it closes the application. Is there a way to be able to close the terminal without closing the gui application ? I tried using nohup, but it didn't work, maybe I used it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I normally ssh to launch applications with a "&" at the end of the whole string ocmando
try this

```
   ssh myremoteserver -f -X myprogram & 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

hope this help you